# ffmpeg generate portrait video but get landscape video

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

portait img info:

```
~/Dropbox/mix/promo $ identify /tmp/mix/promo/cache/handled_img_20861026d9064d972dad09764ac15a8f.jpg
/tmp/mix/promo/cache/handled_img_20861026d9064d972dad09764ac15a8f.jpg JPEG 720x1279 720x1279+0+0 8-bit sRGB 202KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

I use following ffmpeg to gen video

```
ffmpeg -t 2 -i /tmp/mix/promo/cache/handled_img_20861026d9064d972dad09764ac15a8f.jpg -t 2 -i /tmp/mix/promo/cache/handled_img_20861026d9064d972dad09764ac15a8f.jpg  -filter_complex "[0:v]zoompan=z=1:d=60,fade=t=out:st=1.8:d=0.2[v0]; [1:v]zoompan=z=1:d=60,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.2,fade=t=out:st=1.8:d=0.2[v1]; [v0][v1]concat=n=2[v]" -map "[v]" -s 720x1280 -t 4 -y /tmp/t.mp4
```

but get landscape video
[image]

I'm sure this video info is portrait, why does it play landscape video

```
~/Dropbox/mix/promo $ ffprobe /tmp/t.mp4 
ffprobe version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/tmp/t.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 713 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 709 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Answer (score 1):

the solution is, in -vf add portrait scale in each vf end, put scale in vf start still has err, I guess the reason is vf should first gen video and then set its scale

for ex scale=720x1280,setsar=1:1

```
ffmpeg -t 2 -i /tmp/mix/promo/cache/handled_img_20861026d9064d972dad09764ac15a8f.jpg -t 2 -i /tmp/mix/promo/cache/handled_img_20861026d9064d972dad09764ac15a8f.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]zoompan=z=1:d=60,fade=t=out:st=1.8:d=0.2,scale=720x1280,setsar=1:1[v0]; [1:v]zoompan=z=1:d=60,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.2,fade=t=out:st=1.8:d=0.2,scale=720x1280,setsar=1:1[v1]; [v0][v1]concat=n=2[v]" -map "[v]" -s 720x1280 -t 4 -y /tmp/t.mp4
```